# Cygwin, choose between different GCC versions

Tags: gcc, cygwin

I already had Cygwin installed, but I just ran the installer to get a later version of GCC.

Previously I was running GCC 4.9, I am now running 9.3. However, my code now runs approximately 20% slower.

To confirm the GCC version is the cause I would like to be able to compile it with GCC 4.9 again.

How do I do switch between using GCC 4.9 and 9.3?

Comment: You can install an older gcc from cygwin setup. The drop down beside "keep" shows you available older versions. You must select all the gcc packages you have installed because the dependency check will not automatically downgrade installed packages. If this works for you it is much easier than using the Crouching Tiger Hidden Fruit Bat archives, as you may run into compatibility problems with a lot of other development tools.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to install a older Cygwin with the older GCC
from the `Cygwin Time Machine`

http://www.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/Cygwin/timemachine.html

I suggest you to make a parallel installation if you want to compare the results